# Open VPN Client unable to access other subnets which VPN Server can access

Tags: openvpn, iptables, azure

I've setup Open VPN server on a Linux machine in Azure IP (`10.0.3.4`) and the client is a window machine.
My VPN Client is able to connect to the VPN also I'm able to ssh to the VPN server.

I've created another machine in a different subnet (`10.0.1.5`). From my VPN Server i.e. after sshing into the VPN Server, I can `ping 10.0.1.5`. However, my clients cannot ping the same and machines in a different subnet.

So Far,

1. I've enabled IP Forwarding in the NIC card from AZ Portal.
2. `echo 1  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` enabled in VPN Server.
3. `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.27.232.0/24 -d 10.0.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE`

Also regarding step 3 I've doubts. After connecting to VPN I get below IP address. However, my VPN's subnet CIDR block is `10.0.3.0/24` so from where I'm getting IP `172.27.232.2`?

[image: tunnel]

I'm missing some basics here. Appreciate your response.

Referred [This Questtion](https://superuser.com/questions/936819/access-a-subnet-behind-an-openvpn-server) but I don't understand where to add the route? I cannot find `server.conf` file to make changes. I'm on `openvpn 2.7.1.101`. I used the Open VPN Image to set up the VPN server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below to IP Tables in your VPN Server:

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 iptables -F FORWARD`

Follow this guide for [azure](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/microsoft-azure-byol-appliance-quick-start-guide/):

To answer my own question `172.27.232.2` is actually provided to the client by VPN Server from an address range `172.27.224.0/20`by default. you can find it here
https://VPN_SERVER_IP/admin/vpn_settings.

Please ignore/omit point 3 as it's wrong and I had to undo it.